# Performance issues on Chrome when painting many characters at 80-130px font-size range

Tags: performance, google-chrome, fonts, paint, webfonts

I have an unexpected issue where the paint time increases dramatically when resizing text between the 80-130px font-size range. This issue only occurs on Chrome.

I've also noticed that if I reduce the variation in the characters, this issue goes away. Thats the strangest part for me... I wasn't aware of a correlation between Webfont character variation and performance.

I've tried throttling the resize event, reducing content shifts, and setting max heights + overflow to remove the total painted area, but none of that has helped.

This behaviour didn't exist a few months ago, so I'm pretty sure it's something that's been newly added to Chrome — possibly related to how fonts are being rendered. Does anyone know what it could be or how I can address it?

Live demo: https://mckltype.com/fort/#styles

[image]

Below is a video of this behaviour:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1eG4a-bFtjzcHwaNWQCJCj3DYhf4pqaqE/view?usp=sharing

Appologies for not having 'code' in the question; my attempts have had no meaningful impact yet. If it's a problem, I can create a demo here — just shoot me a comment.

Comment: Added this issue to https://issues.chromium.org/issues/327247053